# rspec - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given this code:

```
class Game

  def self.game_board
    return [[][][]]
  end
  def self.empty_output
    '_|_|_'+
    '_|_|_'+
    ' | |'
  end
end
```

and these tests:

```
describe 'It should display a grid' do
  it 'should have empty output' do
    Game.empty_output.should ==
    '_|_|_'+
    '_|_|_'+
    ' | |'
  end
  it 'should have an empty array for the game ' do
    Game.game_board.should ==
    [[][][]]
  end
end
```

why does the test fail that tries to return the array of arrays with the error

```
.F

Failures:

  1) "It should display a grid should be empty
     Failure/Error: return [[][][]]
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
     # ./checkers_rspec.rb:4:in `[]'
     # ./checkers_rspec.rb:4:in `game_board'
     # ./checkers_rspec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00121 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

Comment: Is `[[][][]]` even valid syntactically? Shouldn't that read `[[],[],[]]`?

Comment: Anyone want to take a shot at explaining the error message? ;-)  (type `[][]` into irb for simplest case)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[][][]] should hae been [[],[],[]] in both cases.
```